# Stored procedure error: foreign key references invalid table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spCreateCustomer
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE Persons
    (
        PersonID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        LastName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        FirstName VARCHAR(255),
        Age INT
    );
END
GO

EXEC spCreateCustomer
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE spCreateOrder
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE Orders
    (
        OrderID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        OrderNumber INT NOT NULL,
        PersonID INT,
        CONSTRAINT FK_PersonOrder 
            FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)
    ); 
END
GO
EXEC spCreateOrder
GO
```

Error message:

> Msg 1767, Level 16, State 0, Procedure spCreateOrder, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 25]
>   Foreign key 'FK_PersonOrder' references invalid table 'Persons'

Comment: I think this code should work (because there are `GO`s between each block).  However, I don't recommend putting create table statements in stored procedures, unless you are developing an application where the database structure will be replicated across multiple sites.  And, even in that case, I would suggest a template database of some sort.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for responding, I am developing a web application using asp.net Mvc

Comment: And do not use `sp` prefix, it's reserved by MS.

Comment: Will do Sami, but how do I get solve the error problem of "--Msg 1767, Level 16, State 0, Procedure spCreateOrder, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 25]

--Foreign key 'FK_PersonOrder' references invalid table 'Persons'."

Comment: @Sami `sp` is ok. It's `sp_` that can cause performance issues and unintentional collisions with system sprocs. However, I would still avoid `sp` just because it can easily lead to bad habits and can easily be changed unintentionally to `sp_`.

Comment: How do I solve the error messages....--Msg 1767, Level 16, State 0, Procedure spCreateOrder, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 25] --Foreign key 'FK_PersonOrder' references invalid table 'Persons'.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to put `CREATE TABLE` statement into stored procedures?? What possible benefit would that have?? **Don't do this** - seriously. Any **manipulation** of your database structures should be done explicitly, with "normal" proper SQL statements - don't hide this in stored procedures, this makes absolutely **no sense whatsoever**

Comment: The code in your question will not cause the error (from SSMS) so it seems either the actual code is different or you executing it differently. That said, I agree with @marc_s that creating tables in procs run from asp.net doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Create the table first then create the store procedures that store creation methods. Procedures need to have something to check that exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like everyone said in the comments, creating tables in a stored procedure is not suggested.

But to answer the question, the error you are getting is saying that there is no `Persons` table. This must mean that you are creating the `Orders` table before you are creating the `Persons` table. So you must be executing `spCreateOrder` before `spCreateCustomer`.

If the script is executed as you entered it there are no errors because the table creation is in the proper order. You must be executing the statements in some different order somewhere else.

Comment: So I should just create the table then have a stored procedure for inserting the values into them.

Comment: @P.Coker Exactly. Create the tables you need in the database. Then write stored procedures to get, insert, update, and/or delete data. Then you call the appropriate stored procedure from your code to interact with data in your database.